# apache solr match "convrgys" with "convergys"

Tags: apache, solr

[i am apache solr newbie] Hello i'm trying to match "convrgys" with "convergys", options are use synonyms.txt and add convrgys => convergys something like that or implement auto suggestions using solr 4.3.0. is there a tokenizer or analyzer that can do this job? thanks in advance ;-)

Answer (score 1):

You can check for the following options :-

1. Check [Spell Checking](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SpellCheckComponent) where you can provide suggestions as a Part of response. Did you mean kind
2. [Fuzzy Search](http://lucene.apache.org/core/old_versioned_docs/versions/2_9_1/queryparsersyntax.html#Fuzzy%20Searches) which will enable you to search similar words
3. Synonyms would be a good option to control the search behavior.

Comment: yes, synonyms would be a great option here but seems i need to hard code everything and restart and reindex. kinda weird. i'll try to look at fuzzy search. anyways, thank you @jayendra

Comment: i used [ngram] https://github.com/sunspot/sunspot/wiki/Wildcard-searching-with-ngrams it's good. but it does give me good results on "convergs" but not with "convrgys". I think it stops in "convr" :-(

Comment: n-grams is not for misspelled words. Its rather for matches in between the words or partial words.